# insert and update in the same page codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, sql-update

I want to allow to update or add a new user, but fails to convey the method how to tell if it's new or existing user. Here is the code I wrote:

the model:

```
<?php
```

class Users_model extends CI_Model

{

```
protected $table_name = 'users';

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}



public function get_all_users() {


    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");

    if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {

        foreach ($result->result() as $row) {


            $data[] = $row;


        }


        return $data;

    }


}


public function get_user_id() {

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('id', $this->uri->segment(3));
$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->row();



}

public function insert_user($data) {



    $this->db->insert('users', $data);


    }



public function updata_user($data) {

$this->db->where('id', $this->uri->segment(3));
$this->db->update('users', $data); 



}

}
```

the controller:

```
    function edit () {




    $data['user'] = $this->users_model->get_user_id();
    $data['subview'] = 'admin/user/edit';

    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $data);



}


public function save() {

    $data = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password' => $this->hash($this->input->post('password'),TRUE)


    );

    if ($this->uri->segment(3) == FALSE) {

        $this->users_model->insert_user($data);


    }


    else {


        $result = $this->users_model->updata_user($data);

        if ($result) {


            redirect('users/index');


        }


    }



}
```

the view:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('users/save'); ?>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('name', set_value('name', $user->name)); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('email', set_value('email', $user->email)); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><?php echo form_password('password'); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Confirm password</td>
    <td><?php echo form_password('password_confirm'); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>

    <td></td>
    <td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: Your question is impossible to read. Please clarify

Comment: Created in codeigniter apps updating and adding users. Using the EDIT view page I want to allow user update existing or add new, using the condition "if ($ this-> uri-> segment (3) === false) {
     
     $ this-> users_model-> insert_user ($ data); 
     redirect ('users / index'); 
     } ". 

For some reason it does not work. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 3):

You should check as :

```
if ($ this-> uri-> segment (3) == NULL) { 
      $ this-> users_model-> insert_user ($ data); 
      redirect ('users / index');
}
```

One more suggestion is you should check for emails uniqueness.

Or else one more method is:

1. Create a hidden input text tag for id in your view.
2. Receive that id and check it is NULL or any number.
   Then you can do insert or update in your single method.

I think this would be helpful for you.
If any further more queries comment it. I will help you.